# How to document an object within a class constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3, documentationjs

I am currently using JSDoc to attempt to document the following code...

```
class Test {
  /**
   * @param {Object} raw The raw data.
   */
  constructor(raw) {
    /**
     * Used for things and stuff. It can be useful when referencing Test.myObject.myValue.
     * @type {Object}
     */
    this.myObject = {
      /**
       * This is my string... It does things. Very useful.
       * @type {String}
       */
      myValue: raw.thisIsMyValue
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not entirely sure how to do it. The example above works in VSCode, but not when generating documentation. I've tried a typedef, but that didn't work as it made it a global typedef instead of being a part of the Test class prototype. How do I even do this?

I know how to define an "anonymous" object for a function, using @param, but I have no idea how to do it for a class prototype. I've been Googling for over an hour and a half now with no luck.

Comment: Did you look here? http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-classes.html

Comment: I did, and there doesn't seem to be anything related to this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

1. My debugging method wasn't helping, as the theme I was using for my documentation generator was hiding the properties.
2. When making a typedef, you take out the type right before the object, and then it lists it as properties!

Example

```
class Test {
  /**
   * @param {Object} raw The raw data.
   */
  constructor(raw) {
    /**
     * Used for things and stuff. It can be useful when referencing Test.myObject.myValue.
     * @typedef MyObject
     * @property {String} myValue This is my string... It does things. Very useful.
     */
    this.myObject = {
      myValue: raw.thisIsMyValue
    }
  }
}
```